# Angular 4 property binding refreshing

Tags: angular

i have created one JSON viewer and editor using [Angular4- JsonEditor](https://github.com/manishit56/Angular4-JsonEditor). Application loading time its reading a local json file and populating to view. And its working fine

Now i have one input box and btn. i will enter webservice url in the input box and get the json data as a response. On click of the button am getting the response as expected but the problem is my view is not getting changed.

To populate the data i have used [data]="payLoadData" in component once i get the service response am setting the jsonData but still changes not reflecting in view.

```js
 ngOnInit() {
      this.editorOptions.modes = ['code', 'text', 'tree', 'view']; // set all allowed modes
      this.payLoadData = this.jsondata[0]; // initial file read data
  }
  
  submitSequence(){
    this._responseService.getPayLoadFromUrl()
        .subscribe(data=>{
            this.payLoadData = data;
        },
        error=>{
            console.error(error);
        })
  }
```

```html
<div class="inputSection">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter sequence url">
    <button (click)="submitSequence()">Submit</button>
    <button (click)="generateResponse()">Generate response.json</button>
</div>
<json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [data]="payLoadData"></json-editor>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: No nothing. simply its not refreshing the [data]

Comment: Seems like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/manishit56/Angular4-JsonEditor/issues/6) for this.

Comment: Is it normal that you didn't pass `url` to `getPayLoadFromUrl` ?

Comment: am getting expected result from getPayLoadFromUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you feel inclined to do so, you could edit the [package source](https://github.com/manishit56/Angular4-JsonEditor/blob/master/src/app/component/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.component.ts) to include [`onChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges). For example:

```
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
...
export class JsonEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  ...
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   if(changes.data.firstChange) return;
   this.destroy();
   this.editor = new editor(this.rootElement.nativeElement, this.options, changes.data.currentValue);
  } 
  ...
}
```

This should, in theory, update the property binding when `payLoadData` changes. (unfortunately I have no way of testing this right now.)